# Clarification of a two variables integral over a set.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

We are about to facing integration in many variables over a definite set, and I would like to ask you a clarification about the meaning itself of this.

For example, let's say I have to evaluate the following integral

$$\int_T \frac{1}{x + y} \text{d}x\text{d}y$$

where $T$ is the triangle of vertexes $(1, 0)$, $(0, 2)$, $(1, 2)$.

Ok now, what does perplex me is that I don't have to find, through the integration, the area of that triangle, but I have to calculate what is the integral of the function $\frac{1}{x+y}$ over that triangle.

I find this not easy to understand what is the meaning of this "integration over a triangle", perhaps because of what I am used to think of integrations.

If there were not a set $T$ over which to integrate, what would that integral give (as a meaning I mean)?

Thank you!

Comment: The language of "integration *over* a region" is meant to suggest the graph of a function  $f$ of two variables, defined on that region, i.e. the surface consisting of points $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $z = f(x, y)$. The integral can then be interpreted as the (signed) *volume* of this solid.

Comment: @SammyBlack So if I udnerstand well, it's like a solid with the triangle as a "base" and $f(x, y)$ is the "height"? hence the integral is like a volume integral? Could it also be written as
$$\int_A \text{d}x\text{d}y \int_0^{\frac{1}{x+y}} \text{d}z$$ ?